# Getting console error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In the process of setting up a new React CSR app, some boiler-plate libs, etc etc. Getting this error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (at @emotion_react_macro.js?v=30f6ea37:29894:134)
```

Now I'm not about to go and fix some package that I don't maintain. How do I find the true issue? Vite dev build reports no errors.

Comment: Try this `rm node_modules -rf && npm install`

Comment: @AhmedAbdelbaset no dice. Same error persists after a clearing of the node_modules folder and reinstalling.

Comment: It's probably some unsupported syntax. What's your Node version?

Comment: @code node is 18.6.1 and npm is 9.5.1

Comment: @AhmedAbdelbaset also, not a good assumption to make that I'm on Linux. For all the other windows devs searching for a similar answer, the command is `rd -r node_modules && npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have also faced this type of error.
Check your import.

import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material'